# Getting Error: " formal argument "label.pos" matched by multiple actual arguments" in plotrix::polar.plot

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I am plotting a radial plot of bearing directions and it gives an error with label.pos argument

```
  polar.plot(bear[,2],bear[,1],main="Distribution of Start Points from centre",
                   rp.type="r",labels=c("North","West","South","East"),
label.pos=c(90,180,270,0), 
 clockwise=FALSE, radial.labels = "",
               label.pos=NULL, line.col=c("yellow"),show.radial.grid=FALSE,
               show.grid.labels=1,
               radial.lim=c(0,max(bear[,2]),
                            boxed.radial=FALSE))
```

It gives me an error saying

```
Error in polar.plot(bear[, 2], bear[, 1], main = "Distribution of Start Points from centre",  : 
  formal argument "label.pos" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

How do I change the argument to get the direction on the plot ?

Comment: You have passed the `label.pos` argument twice and thus the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above error can be seen in two occasions which I describe below:

In functions one can use only part of the name of an argument and the function will work. Let's see an example:

```
myfun<-function(ab,aa){
  ab*aa
}
```

Notice that passing one of the arguments as `ab` and the other one as simple `a` will work.

```
> myfun(ab=5, a=4)
[1] 20
```

R is able to understand that since the first named argument is `ab` and the second starts with `a`, that the second argument is actually `aa`.

However, if I try the following it will not work:

```
> myfun(a=5,a=4)
Error in myfun(a = 5, a = 4) : 
  formal argument "ab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

In the above case R does not know which `a` corresponds to `ab` and which to `aa` and thus you get an error same as the one you mention in your question.

The same error appears if you provide the same (correctly named) argument twice:

```
> myfun(aa=5,aa=4)
Error in myfun(aa = 5, aa = 4) : 
  formal argument "aa" matched by multiple actual arguments
```